# Error al usar getRows en ADOdb Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getRows()

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, php5

Al usar la función `getRows` para obtener los datos de una base de datos me sale esto:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getRows

yo estoy usando un

```
$al = $db->getRows("SELECT * FROM RegistroPromedio");
```

Porque si uso `getRow` solo me trae un `array` con un registro.Lo que significa que todo esta bien menos la manera en la que estoy llamando las filas.

Comment: Si necesitan mas información por parte de mi código aquí se los pasare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné no era necesario usar un `getRows` solo me bastó con usar un `getAll` 
    `$al = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM RegistroPromedio");`